# Unable to Select the First Item in a Listview after Item Removal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have listview control.There is an option to remove selected items.After the user removes an item.I need to programatically select the previous item just before the removed item or the First item.I have tried

```
listView.Items[0].Selected = true;
listView.Select();
```

No item is selected or Highlighted.What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView.Select doesn't select an item in the items collection.
The right syntax is

```
if(this.listView1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    this.listView1.Focus();
    this.listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
    this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
}
```

[See MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4x56c0b.aspx)

Comment: @techno, answer updated. Just tested and now works with listview in Large Icons view mode. Probably when you click on button, the focus is on that button, so we don't get a visible clue that a new item is selected in the listview, infact, if you tab to the listview, the item choosen appears selected.

Comment: Thanks.It works.Is there a way to fire the Onclick event upon this selection

Answer (score 0):

The listView's Items Collection does not have a Select() method. Instead call the listView's Select() method. However, in most cases it should work without it.

```
listView.Items[0].Selected = true; 
listView.Select();
```

By the way, "it's not working" is not a good explanation of what is causing you trouble. Be a bit more specific next time.

Comment: There has been a mistake in the code which i had posted its actually 'listView.Select();' .Please see the Edit

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted will work fine.  Are you doing anything else like giving the focus to another control?  The default behavior of the listView is to hide selected items when it loses focus.

Set the property *HideSelection* of the listView to false and see if you are able to see the selection.